# How to prevent SVG inside another SVG clipping

Tags: css, svg, inline-svg

I have an SVG inside another SVG, however the inner SVG is clipping.

[image]

If I inspect element, the inspector shows the correct size rectangle:

[image]

I've been attempting to alter the viewBox on the inner SVG, but with no joy. Is there a technique to displaying it correctly?

```css
.canvas{
  background: #000000;
}
```

```html
<svg width="136" height="200" viewBox="0 0 136 200" class="canvas">
  <g id="grid">
    <line x1="16" x2="112" y1="16" y2="16" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.3)"></line>
    <line x1="16" x2="16" y1="16" y2="176" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.3)"></line>
    <line x1="48" x2="48" y1="16" y2="176" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.3)"></line>
    <line x1="80" x2="80" y1="16" y2="176" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.3)"></line>
    <line x1="112" x2="112" y1="16" y2="176" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.3)"></line>
    <line x1="16" x2="112" y1="48" y2="48" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.3)"></line>
    <line x1="16" x2="112" y1="80" y2="80" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.3)"></line>
    <line x1="16" x2="112" y1="112" y2="112" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.3)"></line>
    <line x1="16" x2="112" y1="144" y2="144" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.3)"></line>
    <line x1="16" x2="112" y1="176" y2="176" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.3)"></line>
  </g>
  <g id="items">
    <svg width="32" height="32" x="32" y="64" style="transform: rotate(90deg);">
      <g>
        <g>
          <rect x="20" y="20" width="24" height="24" fill="#683C34" class=""></rect>
        </g>
        <g>
          <rect x="20" y="28" width="24" height="4" fill="#F4B03C" class=""></rect>
        </g>
        <g>
          <rect x="24" y="20" width="4" height="12" fill="#F4B03C" class=""></rect>
        </g>
        <g>
          <rect x="36" y="20" width="4" height="8" fill="#F4B03C" class=""></rect>
        </g>
        <g>
          <rect x="20" y="32" width="24" height="4" fill="#FFDA70" class=""></rect>
        </g>
        <g>
          <rect x="24" y="36" width="4" height="8" fill="#FFDA70" class=""></rect>
        </g>
        <g>
          <rect x="36" y="36" width="4" height="8" fill="#FFDA70" class=""></rect>
        </g>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Why would you put an svg inside another svg unless you wanted clipping? If you don't want clipping, use a <g> element instead.

Comment: @RobertLongson Because `<g>` elements don't have a width or height I was struggling setting the `transform-orign` to its center. I definitely take your point – I'll give it another bash!

Comment: you probably want transform-box: fill-box;

Answer (score 0):

Your inner SVG is clipping because you have set the `width` and `height` to 32x32. But the contents of your SVG are larger than that.  It is actually 44x44.

How you fix that depends on what you actually want to do. Unfortunately you haven't really explained what exactly you want to happen.

Another problem you have is that `transform` on inner SVGs is a new addition to SVG2, and isn't supported by all browsers yet.

Robert is correct. You probably just need to switch to a `<g>` element.  If you do that you won't have to worry about clipping.  However you'll need to position the shape with `transform` instead of `x` and `y`.

As far as the rotation goes, you can rotate your inner element around its centre in a couple of ways.  But the simplest IMO is as follows:

Use the variant of `rotate()` that takes the centre of rotation coords.  The top-left of your shape is at 20,20 and is 24x24 in size.  So the centre of that is at `20 + 24/2 = 32`.  So you need to use `rotate(90, 32,32). See below.

```css
.canvas{
  background: #000000;
}
```

```html
<svg width="136" height="200" viewBox="0 0 136 200" class="canvas">
  <g id="grid">
    <line x1="16" x2="112" y1="16" y2="16" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.3)"></line>
    <line x1="16" x2="16" y1="16" y2="176" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.3)"></line>
    <line x1="48" x2="48" y1="16" y2="176" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.3)"></line>
    <line x1="80" x2="80" y1="16" y2="176" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.3)"></line>
    <line x1="112" x2="112" y1="16" y2="176" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.3)"></line>
    <line x1="16" x2="112" y1="48" y2="48" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.3)"></line>
    <line x1="16" x2="112" y1="80" y2="80" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.3)"></line>
    <line x1="16" x2="112" y1="112" y2="112" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.3)"></line>
    <line x1="16" x2="112" y1="144" y2="144" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.3)"></line>
    <line x1="16" x2="112" y1="176" y2="176" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.3)"></line>
  </g>
  <g id="items">
    <g transform="translate(32,64) rotate(90, 32,32)">
      <g>
        <g>
          <rect x="20" y="20" width="24" height="24" fill="#683C34" class=""></rect>
        </g>
        <g>
          <rect x="20" y="28" width="24" height="4" fill="#F4B03C" class=""></rect>
        </g>
        <g>
          <rect x="24" y="20" width="4" height="12" fill="#F4B03C" class=""></rect>
        </g>
        <g>
          <rect x="36" y="20" width="4" height="8" fill="#F4B03C" class=""></rect>
        </g>
        <g>
          <rect x="20" y="32" width="24" height="4" fill="#FFDA70" class=""></rect>
        </g>
        <g>
          <rect x="24" y="36" width="4" height="8" fill="#FFDA70" class=""></rect>
        </g>
        <g>
          <rect x="36" y="36" width="4" height="8" fill="#FFDA70" class=""></rect>
        </g>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```